# catkin_make error: undefined reference to `cublasLtGetStatusString@libcublasLt.so.11'

Tags: cmake, anaconda, cuda, ros, catkin

I was trying to compile a ROS project and it reported the following error while executing `catkin_make`

```
[ 84%] Linking CXX executable /home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/featureTrackingNode
[ 86%] Linking CXX executable /home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/plOdometryNode
[ 88%] Linking CXX executable /home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/submapManagerNode
/usr/bin/ld: warning: /home/le/anaconda3/lib/libgomp.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/usr/bin/ld: warning: /home/le/anaconda3/lib/libgomp.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/usr/bin/ld: warning: /home/le/anaconda3/lib/libquadmath.so.0: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/usr/bin/ld: warning: /home/le/anaconda3/lib/libquadmath.so.0: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64/libcublas.so: undefined reference to `cublasLtGetStatusString@libcublasLt.so.11'
/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64/libcublas.so: undefined reference to `cublasLtGetStatusName@libcublasLt.so.11'
/home/le/anaconda3/lib/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to `FT_Done_MM_Var'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GAC-Mapping/gacm/CMakeFiles/plOdometryNode.dir/build.make:531: recipe for target '/home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/plOdometryNode' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/plOdometryNode] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2850: recipe for target 'GAC-Mapping/gacm/CMakeFiles/plOdometryNode.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [GAC-Mapping/gacm/CMakeFiles/plOdometryNode.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The project is:[text](https://github.com/SYSU-RoboticsLab/GAC-Mapping)

I looked up the relevant issues and they all turned out to be related to pytorch in the python/conda environment. For example:

```
OSError: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The current solution about this mistake doesn't seem to solve my problem

```
 undefined reference to `cublasLtGetStatusString@libcublasLt.so.11'
```

nvcc -V output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Aug_15_21:14:11_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.4, V11.4.120
Build cuda_11.4.r11.4/compiler.30300941_0
```

nvidia-smi output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A5000    Off  | 00000000:3B:00.0  On |                    0 |
| 46%   73C    P2   155W / 230W |  20439MiB / 22721MiB |     72%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

After I quit the conda environment, the compilation was successful,

```
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/plOdometryNode
[ 98%] Built target plOdometryNode
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/le/lsq/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gacm/submapManagerNode
[100%] Built target submapManagerNode
```

so I want to know why I get an error when I activate the conda environment?